# CKEditor Angular how to insert text at position but keep formatting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I can insert my merge field text at the current selection with the following code:

```
editor.model.change(writer => {
    var position = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();

    // my attempt to join with last node
    position.stickiness = 'toPrevious';
        
    writer.insertText(text_to_insert, position);
});
```

However, this doesn't retain the styling of the last node and instead uses the default styling. I have looked through the CKEditor docs and saw I could change the position object's stickiness, but this doesn't appear to change anything.

[image]

I'm trying to work out how I can insert text at the position AND keep the previous nodes styling. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: never mind figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

A few hours later I managed to get something working. [The docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#member-selection) were helpful but I kept getting some unexpected behaviour with the selection stuff.

```
editor.model.change(writer => {

    var selection = editor.model.document.selection;
    var position = selection.getFirstPosition();

    // copy attributes of selected element
    var attributes = {};
    if (position.parent.childCount > 0) {
        var element = position.parent.getChild(0);
        attributes = element.getAttributes();
    }

    writer.insertText(text_to_insert, attributes, position);

});
```